# How to generate a white noise matrix of certain amplitude in R?

Tags: r, noise

this is a rather simple question, yet, I struggle to cope with it.

Basically, I want to generate a matrix (2 cols, 10,000 rows). The first column will define a simple sequence (seq(1,10,000,1), the second column should consist of "white noise".

Therefore, I would like to generate a vector (of size 10,000) consisting of white noise. Since the noise should roughly mimic a molecular ion concentration, the noise's values should range between 2e-7 and 1.2e-6.

[image]
Is there an easy way to do this in R?

Many thanks and best wishes!

I added an image below of a calcium signal; of course it would be great to simulate a signal with a similar dynamic but primarily I would like to focus on randomly oscillating dynamics (no defined frequency, minimal changes in amplitudes).

Comment: Yes. There are many random-generator functions,which one to use depends on your intended distribution of white-noise values.

Comment: There are infinitely many distributions. What does a molecular ion concentration look like?

Comment: @Roland oops, sloppy formulating on my part.

Comment: @Roland I know but it has become too slow to open another instance... you're right though... jitter() follows normal distribution apparently... won't be a proper answer... I guess I jumped the gun

Comment: @Gaurav This is not necessarily a wrong answer. A normal distribution of fluctuatons (Gaussian noise) can be "white noise".

Comment: White noise usually refers to a power spectrum - where the amplitude and type of the fluctuations is the same, e.g., for each measured frequency. It doesn't say much about the probability distribution of the fluctuations - only that the mean is zero, and that the variance is finite.

Comment: my bad; usually it should oscillate between the base and the top value. However, for this test I would be satisfied with a total random unpredictive value sequence between the mentioned bottom and top value (i.e. there does not have to be a certain dynamic)

Comment: @Arne You don't seem to understand what we are asking. A purely random variable follows a distribution (e.g., normal, log-normal, uniform, ...). R offers many functions to sample from distributions (e.g., `rnorm`, `rlnorm`, `runif`, ...). Which one to use depends of the desired distribution of your white noise. And the desired distribution should of course approximate the distribution of your molecular ion concentration.

Comment: @Arne for instance, your range seems to indicate only positive values (2e-7 to 1.2e-6). Is that the true range? Or are they the amplitudes? Do you know how you would generate one value? Do you have a sample of what your white noise should look like?

Comment: @Heroka that should be the true range of possible values, yes. I added a snapshot of a calcium measurement above. Of course it would be great if the result would look anything like that, but I wouldn't focus too much on that. The proposal of Elzwawi looks quite good for a first testing phase for my research :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A vector of Gaussian white noise can be generated with rnorm(10000) and you can define a function to set the required range, the following code will generate a vector with the desired range (w.noise):

```
noise <- rnorm(10000)
scale <- function(noise){(noise-min(noise))/(max(noise)-min(noise))*(1.2e-6-2e-7)+2e-7}
w.noise <- scale(noise)
```

Comment: I think after your scaling it won't be Gaussian white noise anymore.

Comment: You are right, it is not strictly Gaussian anymore. But it all depends on what is he trying to simulate.

Comment: many thanks :) - and sorry for the rather imprecise description

Comment: @Arne is your issue fixed now? If so, could you accept the answer?